# Google map direction intent with multiple location on route and starting point as current location, android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I want to start Google map intent for direction with current location as starting position, one location as entry position and other location as destination. 
After googling for this, following is the closest query I came with

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=41.3951982,-72.855568 to: 41.279386, -72.825098
```

OR

```
"https://www.google.com/maps/dir//41.3951982,-72.855568/41.279386,-72.825098"
```

Both of them work good when I paste on browser, but not on my mobile device. I just get source and destination. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Actually the second one works. Unlike browser, it only shows starting location and first point, but has a full navigation route. :)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any google approved way of doing it (as far as I looked to documentation). But I found this solution working pretty good

```
    private void navigate(List<LatLng> latLngs) {
    String uri = "";
    for (LatLng latLng : latLngs) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(uri)) {
            uri = String.format(
                "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%s, %s",
                String.valueOf(latLng.latitude).replace(",", "."),
                String.valueOf(latLng.longitude).replace(",", ".")
            );
        } else {
            if (!uri.contains("&daddr")) {
                uri += String.format(
                    "&daddr=%s, %s",
                    String.valueOf(latLng.latitude).replace(",", "."),
                    String.valueOf(latLng.longitude).replace(",", ".")
                );
            } else {
                uri += String.format(
                    "+to:%s, %s",
                    String.valueOf(latLng.latitude).replace(",", "."),
                    String.valueOf(latLng.longitude).replace(",", ".")
                );
            }
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: your code works but Google Maps doesn't seem to optimize routes this way, any idea how to send the intent in way that Google Maps will calculate the best route possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps app on Android doesn't support multiple destinations. You can try to draw on the map by using native [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes). You can get the directions from [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).